# Binary codes that can correct one error and what is encoded/decoded has rate "arbitrarily close" to $1$

Tags: coding-theory

Task:

> Show that there exist binary codes that can correct one error and that have **rate** **arbitrarily close** to $1$.

This is asking for an existence proof, so either by contruction or using some well-known result, but I do not know where to even start with this. The statement seems so simple but one word is throwing me off: "arbitrarily close", which  means that we can make the rate as close to $1$ as we like. We would have to come up with some code that has better and better rate if we make it larger, maybe the rate would be some fraction of the form $\frac{a-1}{a}$ for some natural number $a$. I think this corresponds to puncturing so-called "[convolutional code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code)"

Does anybody have a hint or tip?

Comment: Can you explain for a code what being close to $1$ means?

Comment: Every bit of information is useful and there is no redundant information.

Comment: @Levent not for the code itself, for the bitrate of what is encoded by code can get arbitrarily close to not having redundancy. I guess it is meant encoded/unencoded can get arbitrarily close to 1.

Comment: That's indeed what is meant, the question is in a way poorly phrased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to look at [Hamming codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code) of increasing length to see the [rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_rate) converging to $1$.

Comment: Yep, that's a good example, I didn't know there were other Hamming codes besides (8,4) and (7,4)